# Understanding Mobile Subscriptions Data View

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, sms

I am trying to get a better understanding of the data being stored in the _MobileSubscriptions view in terms of how it relates to SMS shortcode/keyword subscriptions.

Specifically, is there a row created for each instance of a mobile number being associated with a shortcode and keyword? If so, is there a way to determine what those shortcodes & keywords are? My hope was that the column "SubscriptionDefinitionID" would be the key to making these identifications but it is just returning what looks to be a GUID.

If anyone has "cracked the code" to use the data here to identify out how subscriptions are being stored in this view any information that can help shed some light would be greatly appreciated.